# Understanding self joins and flattening

Tags: google-bigquery

I'll start with the fact that I'm a newbie and I managed to hack this original query together. I've looked over many examples but I'm just not wrapping my head around self joins and displaying the data I want to see.

I'm feeding BQ with mobile app data daily and thus am querying multiple tables. I'm trying to query for a count of fatal crashes by IMEI by date. This query does give me most of the output I want as it returns Date, IMEI and Count.

However, I want the output to be Date, IMEI, Branch, Truck and Count. user_dim.user_properties.key is a nested field and in my query I'm specifically asking for user_dim.user_properties.key = 'imei_id' and getting it's value in user_dim.user_properties.value.value.string_value.

I don't understand how I would  perform the join to also get back the values where user_dim.user_properties.key = 'truck_id' and user_dim.user_properties.key = 'branch_id' and ultimately getting my output to be: Date, IMEI, Branch, Truck and Count in one row.

Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT
  event_dim.date AS Date,
  user_dim.user_properties.value.value.string_value AS IMEI,
COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
    FLATTEN( (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
  TABLE_QUERY([smarttruck-6d137:com_usiinc_android_ANDROID],'table_id CONTAINS "app_events_"')), user_dim.user_properties)
WHERE
  user_dim.user_properties.key = 'imei_id'
  AND event_dim.name = 'app_exception'
  AND event_dim.params.key = 'fatal'
  AND event_dim.params.value.int_value = 1
  AND event_dim.date = '20170807'
GROUP BY
  Date,
  IMEI
ORDER BY
  Count DESC
```

Comment: Please don't try to get started using legacy SQL; I would recommend learning [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query that should work for you, using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  event_dim.date AS Date,
  (SELECT value.value.string_value
   FROM UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
   WHERE key = 'imei_id') AS IMEI,
  (SELECT value.value.string_value
   FROM UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
   WHERE key = 'branch_id') AS branch_id,
  (SELECT value.value.string_value
   FROM UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
   WHERE key = 'truck_id') AS truck_id,
  COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM `smarttruck-6d137.com_usiinc_android_ANDROID.app_events_*`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) AS event_dim
WHERE
  event_dim.name = 'app_exception' AND
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(event_dim.params)
    WHERE key = 'fatal' AND value.int_value = 1
  ) AND
  event_dim.date = '20170807'
GROUP BY
  Date,
  IMEI,
  branch_id,
  truck_id
ORDER BY
  Count DESC;
```

A couple of thoughts/suggestions, though:

- To restrict how much data you scan, you probably want to filter on `_TABLE_SUFFIX = '20170807'` instead of `event_dim.date = '20170807'`. This will be cheaper and (if I understand correctly) will return the same results.
- If the combinations of IMEI, branch_id, and truck_id are unique, there probably isn't a benefit to computing the count, so you can remove the `COUNT(*)` and also the `GROUP BY`/`ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: This is great, thank you. As for the date, I'm using this result in Data Studio which may span one or more days which is why I'm querying multiple tables. If there's a better way, I'm all ears.

Comment: Your help has been great, thank you. Ultimately I'd like to query today's intraday table as well as the last 30 days in one result. I've incorporated _TABLE_SUFFIX as you suggested but how might I get the intraday table involved as well?

Comment: Consider asking a new question if you need more help, but you could maybe take a union, e.g. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT _TABLE_SUFFIX AS date, * FROM YourTable_.* UNION ALL SELECT _TABLE_SUFFIX, * FROM YourIntradayTable_.*`) WHERE ...`.