# Accessing Struct(s) and Array(s) in Firebase Closed Funnels through BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I stumbled unto this standard SQL BigQuery [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nAvz.png) this week, which got me started with a Firebase Analytics Closed Funnel. I however got the wrong results (view image below). There should be no users that had a "Tutorial_LessonCompleted" before they did not start a "Tutorial_LessonStarted >> Lesson = 1 " first. This could be because of various reasons.

**Questions:**

1. Is it wise to use the User Property = "first_open_time", or is it better to use the Event = "first_open". How would the latter implementation look like ?
2. I suspect I am perhaps not correctly drilling down to: Event (String = "Tutorial_LessonStarted") >> parameter (String = "LessonNumber") >> value (String = "lesson1")?
3. How would a filter on _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20170701' possibly work, I read this will be cheaper. Any optimised code suggestions are received with open arms and an up-vote!

   ```
   #standardSQL
   SELECT
     step1, step2, step3, step4, step5, step6,
     COUNT(*) AS funnel_count,
     COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS users 
   FROM (
   SELECT
       user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS user_id,
       event.timestamp_micros AS event_timestamp,
       event.name AS step1,
       LEAD(event.name, 1) OVER (
         PARTITION BY user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id 
         ORDER BY event.timestamp_micros ASC) as step2,
       LEAD(event.name, 2) OVER (
         PARTITION BY user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id 
         ORDER BY event.timestamp_micros ASC) as step3,
       LEAD(event.name, 3) OVER (
         PARTITION BY user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id 
         ORDER BY event.timestamp_micros ASC) as step4,
       LEAD(event.name, 4) OVER (
         PARTITION BY user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id 
         ORDER BY event.timestamp_micros ASC) as step5,
       LEAD(event.name, 5) OVER (
         PARTITION BY user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id 
         ORDER BY event.timestamp_micros ASC) as step6
   FROM
       `......`, 
       UNNEST(event_dim) AS event, 
       UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties) AS user_prop  
   WHERE user_prop.key = "first_open_time"
   ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ASC
   )
   WHERE step6 = "Tutorial_LessonStarted" AND EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM `......`, 
   UNNEST(event_dim) AS event,
   UNNEST(event.params)
   WHERE key = 'LessonNumber' AND value.string_value = "lesson1") GROUP BY step1, step2, step3, step4, step5, step6
   ORDER BY funnel_count DESC
   LIMIT 100;
   ```

**Note:**

1. Enter your query table FROM, i.e:`project_id.com_game_example_IOS.app_events_20170212`,
2. I left out the funnel_count and user_count.

**Output:**

[image: Output]

### ----------------------------------------------------------

Update since original question above:

@Elliot: I don’t understand why you said:  -- ensure that an event with lesson1 precedes Tutorial_LessonStarted.

Tutorial_LessonStarted has a parameter "LessonNumber" with values lesson1,lesson2,lesson3,lesson4.

I want to count all funnels that took place with a last step in the funnel equal to LessonNumber=lesson1.

So, applied to event log-data for a brand new user's first session (aka: an user that fired first_open_time), the answer would be the table below:

- View.OnboardingWelcomePage
- View.OnboardingFinalPage
- **View.JamLoading**
- **View.JamLoading**
- **Jam.UserViewsJam**
- **Jam.ProjectOpened**
- **View.JamMixer**
- **Tutorial.LessonStarted (This parameter “LessonNumber"'s value would be equal to “lesson1”)**
- Jam.ProjectPlayStarted
- View.JamLoopSelector
- View.JamMixer
- View.JamLoopSelector
- View.JamMixer
- View.JamLoopSelector
- View.JamMixer
- Tutorial.LessonCompleted
- Tutorial.LessonStarted (This parameter “LessonNumber"'s value would be equal to “lesson2”)

So it is important to firstly get all the users that had a **first_open_time** on a specific day, as well structure the events into a funnel so that the last event in the funnel is one which matches an event and a specific parameter value, and then form the funnel "backwards" from there.

[image]

Comment: Can you see if my answer on this question helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45575234/6253347. It has an example of retrieving a `string_value` for a particular `key` in the select list.

Answer (score 2):

Let me go through some explanation, then see if I can suggest a query to get you started.

It looks like you want to analyze the sequence of events in your analytics data, but the sequence is already there for you--you have an array of the events. Looking at the [Firebase schema for BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en), `event_dim` is the relevant column, and unless I'm misunderstanding something, these events are ordered by time. If you want to check what the sixth event's name was, you can use:

```
event_dim[SAFE_ORDINAL(6)].name
```

This will evaluate to `NULL` if there were fewer than six events, or else it will give you the string with the event name.

Another observation is that you are attempting to analyze both `event_dim` and `user_dim`, but you are taking the cross product of the two, which will explode the number of rows and make it hard to reason about the results of the query. To look for a specific user property, use an expression of this form:

```
(SELECT value.value.string_value
 FROM UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
 WHERE key = 'first_open_time') = '<expected property value>'
```

Combining these two filters, your `FROM` and `WHERE` clause would look something like this:

```
FROM `project_id.com_game_example_IOS.app_events_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20170701' AND
  event_dim[SAFE_ORDINAL(6)].name = 'Tutorial_LessonStarted' AND
  (SELECT value.value.string_value
   FROM UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
   WHERE key = 'first_open_time') = '<expected property value>'
```

Using the bracket operator to access the steps from `event_dim`, we can do something like this:

```
WITH FilteredInput AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM `project_id.com_game_example_IOS.app_events_*`
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20170701' AND
    event_dim[SAFE_ORDINAL(6)].name = 'Tutorial_LessonStarted' AND
    (SELECT value.value.string_value
     FROM UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
     WHERE key = 'first_open_time') = '<expected property value>' AND
    -- ensure that an event with lesson1 precedes Tutorial_LessonStarted
    EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM UNNEST(event_dim) WITH OFFSET event_offset
      CROSS JOIN UNNEST(params)
      WHERE key = 'LessonNumber' AND
        value.string_value = 'lesson1' AND
        event_offset < 5
    )
)
SELECT
  event_dim[ORDINAL(1)].name AS step1,
  event_dim[ORDINAL(2)].name AS step2,
  event_dim[ORDINAL(3)].name AS step3,
  event_dim[ORDINAL(4)].name AS step4,
  event_dim[ORDINAL(5)].name AS step5,
  event_dim[ORDINAL(6)].name AS step6,
  COUNT(*) AS funnel_count,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_dim.user_id) AS users
FROM FilteredInput
GROUP BY step1, step2, step3, step4, step5, step6;
```

This will return all unique "paths" along with a count and number of distinct users for each. Note that I'm just writing this off the top of my head--I don't have representative data that I can try it on--so there may be syntax or other errors.

Comment: Hi Elliot, thanks for taking the time to reply, sorry for the delay in my comment. I have updated my question above based on your feedback. I ran the code, but received no output. I am just uncertain about one piece of the code (which I stated in my question above). The core thinking behind this query comes from: "Step 2: Calculate users for journey that ends with spending virtual currency" in this post, https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/04/how-to-do-cross-platform-analytics-with-google-bigquery. Let me know whether you need more clarification. Thanks again for the big help :)

Comment: That part is modeled by the `event_dim[SAFE_ORDINAL(6)].name = 'Tutorial_LessonStarted'` in my answer (you don't need to use `LEAD` when you can use array operators). I would suggest removing one or two conditions at a time and check the output that you receive to see where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Elliott, I commented out the "first_open_time" clause, I looked at the Firebase logs and the value is always "null" (will follow-up with a Firebase PO). I got results for the script and is extremely low funnel_count of 20 and zero user_counts (compared to 7K which I expected). This brings me to the next question: does this closed funnel explicitly only give me the funnels of sessions that ended on the TutorialStarted (pure app exits), or just sessions of users that somewhere went through this closed funnel and did not necessarily exit the app after reaching the TutorialStarted-event ?

Comment: This is looking for sessions where the sixth event is `TutorialStarted` based on your original question. If you are looking for the last event, you can use `event_dim[ORDINAL(ARRAY_LENGTH(event_dim))].name = 'Tutorial_LessonStarted'`.